# Display message for first time viewer only

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

Im trying to display a welcome message for a few seconds then have it fade out and not return (unless user deletes cookies). I know i can do this 2 ways using either js cookies or localStorage. This is the code i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('messageState') != 'shown'){
        $("#message").delay(2000).fadeOut();
        localStorage.setItem('messageState','shown')
    }

    $('#message').fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

But it's not fading out. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Or would i be better using js cookie?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2D67/1786/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your last line, the `});` and the fadeout works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('messageState') != 'shown'){
        $("#message").delay(2000).fadeOut();
        localStorage.setItem('messageState','shown')
    }


    $('#message').fadeOut(); 
});
```

Comment: After the message has been loaded. When you refresh the message appears and fades out very quickly. Is there a way to stop this? I've tried adding class hide on fadeout but it's removed on refresh.

Comment: I would personally hide it first, fade in if they are new and then fade out.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong, the closing bracket

```
 })
```

does not belong

Localstorage would be a fine way to store something like this, I usually go by the rule that localstorage is for data I want to read on the front end and cookies are primarily for reading server-side

Comment: How did i miss that! Answer was staring at me all this time. Thanks